# How to apply the style only if next element has specific class?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Markup:

```
<li class="divider"></li>
<li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
```

How do I add a style the first `.divider` only if `.active` is the next sibling?

I was thinking of `.divider + .active` but that would apply styles to `.active`.

```
.divider {
  border-left: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
}
.active {
  background: #fff;
}
// when the next sibling is .active, border-color: transparent;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot select a previous element in CSS as of now, what you can do is either manually target the class by providing some distinct class to it like

```
<li class="divider target_me"></li>
```

And than simply use

```
ul.class_name li.target_me {
   /* Styles goes here */
}
```

Else, if it's the first child of `li`

You can use `ul.class_name li:first-child`, if it's not, simply use `nth-of-type(n)`, substitute `n` with the nth number of your `li`, this way you don't need to call classes too.

For example

```
ul.class_name li:nth-of-type(2) {
   /* Styles here */
}
```

The above selector will select `2nd` child of `ul` element with that specified class name.

---

Still not happy with CSS? You can opt for JS/jQuery solution, but if the markup is static, I would suggest you to use `nth` and if you have access to markup you can atleast call class on the element you want to style..

---

Note: You cannot nest `li` tag as a direct child to `li`, consider changing your markup to below ..

```
<ul>
   <li>
       <a href="#">Home</a>
       <ul>
          <li>Sub</li>
       </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

This *could* work for you:

```css
div {
    color: black;
    float: right;
}

.active + div {
    color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class='third'>third</div>
<div class='second active'>second</div>
<div class='first'>first</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2gcs2/)

Answer (score 1):

CSS doesn't have direct support for this as of now, but jQuery makes it relatively painless, and assuming this is a requirement for your project, could well be the way to go.

In jQuery it would be written something like this:

```
if element.next().hasClass('active'){
    element.addClass('divider')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/D6rRB/)

**CSS**

```
.divactive {
  border-left: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {

  $('.active').prev('.divider').addClass('divactive');

  //or

  $('.active').prev('.divider').css({ 'border-left': '1px solid transparent' });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the design of your navigation tree, but I was facing a similar issue and decided to target the next sibling instead like so:

```
:not(.divider:first-of-type):not(.active + .divider) {
  border-left: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
}
```